# MSSQL - howto to get full list from interval of IDs

Tags: sql

I have two tables

**Created_Labels**:

[image]

- **IF** `label_ID_from = label_ID_to` (it means it has been only one label created), in column `label_number` is number of created label.
- **IF** `label_ID_from <> label_ID_to` (more labels was created), in column `label_number` is `NULL` and in next two columns is interval of created labels with `ID` from table bellow.

**Labels** (list of existing lables):

[image]

How can I get the complete list of created `label_numbers` (get labels with ID 105, 110, 111, 112..120, 200, 201, 202..210, 394, 554)?

[image]

Comment: From your example label 100001 appears in both tables for id = 105 so it should be enough just to select entire Labels table... Or I didn't understand the question

Comment: I need to select IDs 105, 110, 111..120, 200, 201, 202..210, 394, 554

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
      L.ID
    , L.label_number
FROM
      Labels L
  JOIN
      Created_Labels CL
    ON
      L.ID BETWEEN CL.label_ID_from
               AND CL.label_ID_to
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
SELECT distinct label_number
 FROM created_labeles c;
```

OR

> ```
> SELEC distinct l.label_number
>  FROM created_labeles c,
>       labels l
> WHERE c.label_number = l.label_numbers(+)
>   AND c.label_number is null
> ```

The above second query is the left outer join equivalent in Oracle SQl.